# Deploy TBMQ into Kubernetes via terraform not by Helm

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

I want to deploy a [TBMQ](https://thingsboard.io/docs/mqtt-broker/getting-started/) MQTT broker into a kubernetes cluster.
I succeded for minikube, but can't do this via terraform to my remote cluster.
TBMQ does not provide Helm chart package.

What approach should I take?

My try was to create a `null_resource` type of resource with a provisioner. Then I would like to execute command with git clone repository followed by calling 2 scripts that are necessary to call for TBMQ installation.

```
resource "null_resource" "installTBMQ" {
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    command = "git clone -b release-1.2.1 https://github.com/thingsboard/tbmq.git | cd tbmq/k8s/minikube | bash k8s-install-tbmq.sh | bash k8s-deploy-tbmq.sh"
  } 
  depends_on = ...
}
```

Could someone suggest better approach? If not, could someone provide a working example of provisioner similar to the one I want to create?